Most efficient way to get the minimum and maximum values of the primary key of a Mongo collection
I am thinking the most performant way for collection myColl would be:
db.myColl.find().sort( {_id : 1 }).limit( 1 );   // get min
db.myColl.find().sort( {_id : -1 }).limit( 1 );   // get max

Is there some way to avoid the sort() ?
The _id in this case is an integer that increases by 1 on each insert.

It depends what you mean when you say 'avoid the sort'. But in short, what you show there is the most efficient approach.

Did you have a look at the explain plan?

What do you mean by minimum and maximum of primary key. Are your _id numeric or string? If they are some types with no meaningful sorting to you, they will not have meaningful max/min

You can use an Aggregate operators $max and $min. These can be used with aggregation $group stage. Though you will avoid the sort , it will still be a stateful operation. You may have to compare your existing and the aggregation and see which performs better. Using the aggregation query allows one query to get both values.

The _id's in MongoDB are autogenerated ObjectIds according to the timestamp and as mentioned in the documentation, the last 3bytes are are incrementing counted, the documents inside the collection are sorted by default. Therefore, to find the min _id, you can find the first document whereas to find the max _id, the last document inserted will have the max _id.
In other case, if in your use case, the _ids are defined while insertion, the above mentioned queries are the most efficient queries to find the min and max _id in the collection.
Best Regards
Aasawari

There are too much assumption here. OP did not indicate that the _id is in ObjectId type, let alone the auto population. You are also assuming the sorting OP is expecting is the insertion order, which may not be true.

You also don't specify how to find the "first" or "last" document even if some of the other assertions are correct
